# AWK COLRM issue

Tags: unix, awk

Got some UNIX command line work for uni and I am stuck with removing the last line in a column using AWK. I have tried:

```
awk '{colrm [$14]}' /Users/Jak/Documents/colrmeg.txt
```

but after opening the file the last column $14 is still there. Would appreciate any help, cheers!

Comment: `colrm` is not a command, you are kind of using an array. Not sure what you are doing here. Better update with some sample input.

Comment: `colrm` is a command available at your shell prompt. Not part of `awk`. Why are you involving `awk` here at all?

Comment: Ah ok I understand now. I'm rather new to this sort of task so because we were told it was an "AWK Lecture" I presumed all the tasks were with AWK. So what would be the syntax to simply remove the last column? Cheers

Comment: "I am stuck with **removing the last line in a column** " what is that mean?

Comment: Removing the last column*, my bad sorry

Comment: Would i be right to think the syntax would be: colrm [14] filepath?

Comment: does this help you @ThunderGrad? `awk 'NF--' file` ?

Comment: I ran that command Kent and the final column is still there "awk 'NF--' /Users/Jak/Documents/colrmeg.txt"
Output: abcdefghijklmn

Comment: [edit] your question after reading [ask]. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Update - i ran "colrm 14 < filename"  and achieved my goal. Many thanks guys

Comment: You said this is part of an Awk Lecture so I doubt if your teacher is looking for a shell (or C or Perl or or...) solution. If I were you I wouldn't declare victory just yet! The command kent suggested is awk version specific BUT the important thing is that your idea of "columns" is not the same as the default awk idea of "columns" (which Kent assumed). Post sample input and expected output if you'd like help.

Comment: Thanks Ed but it turned out that that part of the task wasn't actually including AWK so the inbuilt UNIX colrm was a fine solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original script did nothing...  The interpretation would be that we matched for every line, then accessed an associative array called *colorm* with whatever was in column 14 as index... If we use **gawk** with the *--lint* switch, we can get a glimpse into why there might be a problem:

```
$ echo foo | gawk --lint '{colrm [$14]}'
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: statement may have no effect
gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) warning: reference to uninitialized field `$14'
gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) warning: reference to uninitialized element `colrm[""]'
gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) warning: subscript of array `colrm' is null string
```

If we want to remove column 14, and if we are space delimited... then the easiest way (that I can think of) to do this would be to use **cut**.

```
cut --complement -d ' ' -f 14 /Users/Jak/Documents/colrmeg.txt
```

If we are keen on using **awk** to do the same:

```
LC_ALL=C awk 'NR < 14 { print; next } { printf("%s", $1); for (i=1; i<14; i++) printf("%s%s", OFS, $i); print "" }' /Users/Jak/Documents/colrmeg.txt
```

Neither script will touch the original input file, but will print to screen. We can direct the output to a new file by tacking *> newfilename.txt* to the end of the command.